# Open a URL on unity3d push notification from parse?

Tags: parsing, unity-game-engine, notifications, push

How can I can open a URL when the user touches the notification on Android?
I know that I should put some fields in JSON when I'm sending the push, what I need is the notification handler in unity.

Comment: you should've utilized the Parse Push receivers 7 years ago

Answer (score -1):

If you use pushwoosh to send notifications it is possible to make it as desired.

Comment: I'm sure Parse can do that as well, I'm not willing to deal with it myself, so I'm asking if anyone did that before.